# Add tag<a> to message from textarea in python flask

Tags: python, flask

How can I add a  tag to extracted tags from post from textarea ?

When I add post I have function that split #hastags from post and add to databse and everything works fine.

But I was wondering how I can add tag  to every #hastags:

```
This is my post with #hashtags #sport #music
```

And I wolud like to add this message like this:

```
This is my post with <a href="/tag/hashtag">#hashtags</a> <a href="/tag/sport">#sport</a> <a href="/tag/music">#music</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this:

```
import re

text = "This is my post with #hashtags #sport #music"
hashtags = re.findall('#[\w]*', text)

if hashtags:
    a_href = '<a href="/tag/{}">{}</a>'
    for tag in hashtags:
        text = text.replace(tag, a_href.format(tag[1:], tag))
```

I do not know what you expect especially from flask? If you need more power in specifying the links and format check out: [anchorman](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/anchorman)